# Reformat regular diff patch to git format

Tags: git, diff, patch

Is there an easy way to reformat a regular (unified) diff patch into a git-format patch? What I want to do, is take a regular patch someone sends me and apply it with git, adding author information – as if it were a git-format patch.

I don't really want to start manually rewriting the patch, so I was wondering if there is perhaps a git command I haven't found out about yet that does this.

It seems like a problem others must have had before...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but if you use `diff -u file1 file2` will generate the patch with the format as `git-patch`

Comment: But without author information... I would like to change the diff into git-patch format, adding the author so I can give credit.

Answer (score 3):

```
git apply < patch; git commit; git format-patch HEAD^
```

Comment: Hmm... But I would have applied the patch and committed it without author information here. I want to add author information **before** I apply and commit, so the person who sent the non-git diff still gets credit.

Comment: @wvh You can pass the `--author` flag to commit, and I guess you don't need the format-patch step.